# Limiting StaticText width

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a panel with several sizers and some gauges that I want to expand to the size of the area or frame that the panel is placed in which is working fine. I'm experiencing a problem however when a StaticText increases to a size that will be larger than the space available, expanding the edges of the panel and the gauges off the screen or visible area. I was wondering if there was a way to stop the text from doing that by snipping it short with a ... without specifying a precise size, basically so it knows where the edge of the display area is. I can get around it by moving the texts that I update to their own panels so I can call Update on their panels, leaving the gauges to be the same size, but the text still runs out of my StaticBox and off the display which isn't ideal.

I could wrap the text down a line but I notice wrap breaks on spaces and as my long text is a file path it is likely to not have spaces, is it possible to break on something other than spaces?

Either wrapping or truncating would be ok, just to stop it running over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You you can't wrap the StaticText content, then the only solution I
can see is to "ellipsize" it, i.e. shortening it by prepending or
appending "..." to the file path. To do that, however, I believe your
best bet would be to go owner-drawn (or simply subclass
wx.lib.stattext), measuring the text size on the OnSize event for your
control and, if needed, prepend/append the "..." to you path.

Attached a proof of concept, with "ellipsization" at the end (i.e.,
"..." is appended and file name is truncated at the end). I gather it
would be trivial to extend to prepending the "..." instead of
appending.

Oh, by the way, in wxPython 2.9 you can also use
wx.StaticText.Ellipsize to (maybe) do the same thing, although I have
never used it myself.

Code sample:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.stattext import GenStaticText as StaticText

if wx.Platform == "__WXMAC__":
    from Carbon.Appearance import kThemeBrushDialogBackgroundActive


class EllipticStaticText(StaticText):

    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='', pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 style=0, name="ellipticstatictext"):
        """
        Default class constructor.

        :param `parent`: the L{EllipticStaticText} parent. Must not be ``None``;
        :param `id`: window identifier. A value of -1 indicates a default value;
        :param `label`: the text label;
        :param `pos`: the control position. A value of (-1, -1) indicates a default position,
         chosen by either the windowing system or wxPython, depending on platform;
        :param `size`: the control size. A value of (-1, -1) indicates a default size,
         chosen by either the windowing system or wxPython, depending on platform;
        :param `style`: the static text style;
        :param `name`: the window name.
        """

        StaticText.__init__(self, parent, id, label, pos, size, style, name)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)


    def OnSize(self, event):
        """
        Handles the ``wx.EVT_SIZE`` event for L{EllipticStaticText}.

        :param `event`: a `wx.SizeEvent` event to be processed.
        """

        event.Skip()
        self.Refresh()


    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        """
        Handles the ``wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND`` event for L{EllipticStaticText}.

        :param `event`: a `wx.EraseEvent` event to be processed.

        :note: This is intentionally empty to reduce flicker.
        """

        pass


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        """
        Handles the ``wx.EVT_PAINT`` event for L{EllipticStaticText}.

        :param `event`: a `wx.PaintEvent` to be processed.
        """

        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)        
        width, height = self.GetClientSize()

        if not width or not height:
            return

        clr = self.GetBackgroundColour()

        if wx.Platform == "__WXMAC__":
            # if colour is still the default then use the theme's  background on Mac
            themeColour = wx.MacThemeColour(kThemeBrushDialogBackgroundActive)
            backBrush = wx.Brush(themeColour)
        else:
            backBrush = wx.Brush(clr, wx.SOLID)

        dc.SetBackground(backBrush)
        dc.Clear()

        if self.IsEnabled():
            dc.SetTextForeground(self.GetForegroundColour())
        else:
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_GRAYTEXT))

        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())

        label = self.GetLabel()
        text = self.ChopText(dc, label, width)

        dc.DrawText(text, 0, 0)


    def ChopText(self, dc, text, max_size):
        """
        Chops the input `text` if its size does not fit in `max_size`, by cutting the
        text and adding ellipsis at the end.

        :param `dc`: a `wx.DC` device context;
        :param `text`: the text to chop;
        :param `max_size`: the maximum size in which the text should fit.
        """

        # first check if the text fits with no problems
        x, y = dc.GetTextExtent(text)

        if x <= max_size:
            return text

        textLen = len(text)
        last_good_length = 0

        for i in xrange(textLen, -1, -1):
            s = text[0:i]
            s += "..."

            x, y = dc.GetTextExtent(s)
            last_good_length = i

            if x < max_size:
                break

        ret = text[0:last_good_length] + "..."    
        return ret


    def Example():

        app = wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "EllipticStaticText example ;-)", size=(400, 300))

        panel = wx.Panel(frame, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        elliptic = EllipticStaticText(panel, -1, r"F:\myreservoir\re\util\python\hm_evaluation\data\HM_Evaluation_0.9.9.7.exe")
        whitePanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1)
        whitePanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        sizer.Add(elliptic, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        sizer.Add(whitePanel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Layout()

        frame.CenterOnScreen()
        frame.Show()

        app.MainLoop()


    if __name__ == "__main__":

        Example()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect!! and I dont even need to make the change to prepend the ellipse because it already does :) Where you check the length of the string with an ellipse it always fits perfectly!

Comment: Just a quick question, because my text is on a StaticBox (which has a greyish transparent background on mac) The colour that the OnPaint method gives is off, I've tried taking out the bit where it gets the background colour but then it paints white, and I've tried taking out clear but then the text doesn't clear and it paints over the top. Hopefully I'll figure it out in a minute but can't seem to get it?

Comment: I think you will want to replace the wx.BufferedPaintDC with wx.PaintDC in the OnPaint method, remove the OnEraseBackground bind and method, and add this `self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_SYSTEM)` to your `__init__` method.